# How to install SNMP

Tags: snmp

I installed Ubuntu on my black BEAGLEBONE and now need to install SNMP, but use
`apt-get install snmp snmpd` and gives error. How to install SNMP?

Comment: It would be helpful if you copied the error message into your question text as well. It could numerous things from your internet connection to the need to run sudo apt-get update first.

Answer (score 2):

Before you typed `sudo apt-get install` did you type a `sudo apt-get update` first?

I usually have this problem on a VPS that I use, after a fresh install i have to type the apt-get update and only then i can install packages.

Answer (score 1):

use these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snmpd snmp
```

After installation, you can view the service status with the following command:

```
sudo service snmpd status
```

finally, you must configure snmp. (`/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`)

Answer (score 0):

To install the snmp on Ubuntu first make sure that your local package list is updated with:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And install the package with:

```
sudo apt-get install snmp
```

Reference:

https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/trusty/main/snmp/